# Why does the reputation graph only scale for lost reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I am referring to this graph, found under the reputation tab on profile pages:
[image: Reputation Graph]
It's very difficult to read for people like me that do not regularly gain or lose large amounts of reputation because everything is squished to the bottom of the graph. It still shows up to 200.

However, whenI select an area on the bottom bar with only negative reputation change, it *does* scale:
[image: Negative Rep Scaling]

If there is any positive reputation in the selection, however, it stays squished:
[image: Positive Selection]
[image: + and - selection]

Why is this? It would be very convenient if it scaled to match whatever the reputation was, sort of like this:
[image: Image Scaling Mockup]

Comment: To highlight how far you got to 200, the standard rep cap.